# ORDER BY ADDED to QUERY

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_artID` WHERE $roku ORDER BY RAND()
```

$roku is a series of OR statements that are being sent from a Roku running a slideshow like this:

```
artID=21 OR artID=212 OR artID=5 OR etc
```

It sends back an RSS xml list.

Is there an `ORDER BY` statement that will return the results in the order that they are query'd? There is no column in the DB to reference, this is a list of "User Favorites" of photographs, and there is no existing order to reference. If i remove the `ORDER BY` statement, it of course returns the results in the order of the Key column (`artID`) which is not what i want.

Comment: `... ORDER BY FIELD(artID,'3','7','5')...`

Comment: MAybe I'm not being clear, I don't know what the order will be, I need it to be in the order of the "OR" list that is sent, It would need it to be like ORDER BY LIST  which doesnt exist. thanks for responding though.

Comment: I think what he said is what you want. Is this more clear? `SELECT * FROM tbl_artID WHERE $roku ORDER BY FIELD(artID, 21, 212, 5)`

Comment: so populate the field list just like you populate the order by. how ever $roku is created it gives you the ids, so use them for a variable to put in the FIELD list

Comment: WHERE artID=5 OR artID=20 or artID=212 - I need it to return the items in that order - 5,20,212, But I don't know beforehand what the order will be so i cant put ID's in the ORDER BY statement. Again i want them un the order they are listed but I'm not making the order, the user is, so i cant guess what it will be

Comment: I know the ID's, its my database, i could order them by artID any way, thats not what i want, i need the order the user selects  - the artID is just to pull the correct images.

Comment: again ... you create the var $roku, when you do that create the var that has the id list, and put that in the field for the query, don't know how to be any clearer than that.

Comment: DAGON - OK i just got what you are saying - I will try that, i will have to manipulate the PHP a bit - Thank you all.